# VB webkit InvokeMember

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webkit, click

Having a problem with vb code, basically trying to auto click a button on a webpage with webkit and its not working.

Working code:

```
'WebKitBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value",    TextBox1.Text)
WebKitBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
```

Not working code:

```
WebKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("Document.getElementById('loginbutton').click()")
```

Error:

> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use java id and auto clicks in WebKit use the following example code:

```
WebKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("javascript:void(document.‌​getElementById('persist_box').click())")
```